# zsh offset mystery: ${1:0:1} == ${1:1:1}

Tags: zsh

This has me floored:

```
function x
{
    echo "/${1:0:1}/${1:1:1}/${1:2:1}/${1:3:1}/${1:4:1}/${1:5:1}/"
}

$ x 123456
```

in zsh prints:

```
/1/1/2/3/4/5/
```

in bash prints:

```
/1/2/3/4/5/6/
```

Everything I've read says that zsh uses zero offset, just like bash, so how on earth can `${1:0:1}` = `${1:1:1}`?

Comment: Pardon Gentlemen, a syntax error. The fact that the above 'sort of worked' made me think that the problem wasn't syntax as such. Seems that zsh and bash are more different than I was expecting. And now I see that I can't use: $1[0,1] I hafta: var=$1; $var[0,1]; to make it work :(

Comment: ... and I find that: $var[0,0] doesn't exist, so it seems that offsets are one based, not zero based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything I've read says that zsh uses zero offset, just like bash, so how on earth can ${1:0:1} == ${1:1:1} ??

Not true unless you set `ksharrays`. Even in this case `${1:0:1}` will preserve its behavior, this option only applies to `${array[subscript]}/${a[s1,s2]}` form, not to `${array:subscript}/${a:s:l}` one. Handling of such form is described in section «PARAMETER EXPANSION» in `man zshexpn`. Form `${a[s1,s2]}` is described in section «ARRAY PARAMETERS» in `man zshparam`.

Answer (score 2):

Offsets in `${name:offset}` or `${name:offset:length}` always start at 0, regardless of the value of the `ksh_array` option (unlike in `$name[offset]`). But there is an exception, which is [documented](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

> For further compatibility with other shells there is a special case for array offset 0. This usually accesses to the first element of the array. However, if the substitution refers the positional parameter array, e.g. `$@` or `$*`, then offset 0 instead refers to `$0`, offset 1 refers to `$1`, and so on. In other words, the positional parameter array is effectively extended by prepending `$0`. Hence `${*:0:1}` substitutes `$0` and `${*:1:1}` substitutes `$1`.

It looks like individual positional parameters are also affected by this exception:

```
zsh -c 'x=abcdef; set ABCDEF; echo ${1:1:1} ${x:1:1}'
A b
```

This looks like a bug, as the restriction only makes sense for the positional parameter array. Thanks for [reporting it](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2011/msg01455.html); there's a [patch](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2011/msg01459.html) which should be incorporated in 4.3.16.

Comment: Hard to believe that such a simple thing can not have been noticed. Where would I report it? Or maybe I should just go back to bash, I've spend the last few days trying to convert my functions to zsh and there is no end of trouble. Just now I find I can no longer grab a keystroke with 'read'.

Comment: function z
{
var=$1
echo "var:/${1:0:1}/${1:1:1}/${1:2:1}/"
echo "var:/${var:0:1}/${var:1:1}/${var:2:1}/"

}

$ z abcde

var: /a/a/b/
var: /a/b/c/

Comment: Sorry, that looks awful, but I can't answer my own question, and the comment box won't format. The bottom line is that if I ' var=$1 ' then things work as I'd expect. This is all so very strange

Comment: @rayandrews [What bugs are currently known and unfixed? Where do I report bugs?](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq06.html#l57)

Answer (score 0):

```
function z
{
  var=$1
  echo "var:/${1:0:1}/${1:1:1}/${1:2:1}/"
  echo "var:/${var:0:1}/${var:1:1}/${var:2:1}/"
}
```

$ z abcde

var: /a/a/b/

var: /a/b/c/

Comment: Thanks; looks like it'll be [fixed in the next version](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2011/msg01459.html).